# What will be the consequences of this citation [?] error?

Tags: citations, thesis, masters, degree

I have recently submitted my thesis but there are some citation errors [?]. I am really in a disaster and cant sleep properly. I think I will get sick soon. What should I do? Can anyone guide me? Do I contact with my supervisor?

Comment: Did you check the label of the citation ?

Comment: This kind of thing is not handled in the same way in all places, so you've got to ask somebody in your department, optimally your supervisor.

Comment: Most importantly I can not edit now because it was final printed version. So I am hoping I will fail due to this. Should I still contact with my supervisor?

Comment: You have not answered my question yet. Was it due to a simple typo or something else ? If it was a simple typo, I think everyone would understand, I don't think you will fail the exam. However, if it was something more serious, it will depend on your exam committee. You need to be ready to explain to them what really happened.

Comment: hi@Nobody sorry not to give the answer..yeah it was a typing error and thats why its appear[?].... later i have corrected. yeah it was serious but i was not.  So i have to get this consequence if i fail.

Comment: Your exam will not fail because of a stinking typing error. You show the committee the LaTex source why [?] appeared. They will understand. Why would they fail you because of that tiny error ? But, if you have more serious problems, it'll be hard to say. Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks@Nobody  i do not have serious problem except this..implementation has met all the requirements.

Comment: "Should I still contact with my supervisor?" If you can't sleep without doing that, it's probably the right thing to do.

Comment: You'll be fine until you become president of Harvard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have submitted your thesis for examination, and noticed some errors.  An unresolved citation is not going to kill your thesis.  You will have a chance to fix any errors at a later date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was the printed final version of my thesis and submitted to the exam office..do not know what will happen now...cant edit anymore

Comment: Have a look at the examination process of your university.

Comment: yeah no way to edit..

Comment: What I mean is that once your thesis returned from examination, you will be able to edit.  It is normal that you won't be able to edit during the examination process.

Comment: may i fail with this citation error?

Comment: @danobdon No one would know if you'll fail the exam except the exam committee. Did you check what caused the citation error [?] ? Was it just wrong label which caused [?] ? (assuming you used LaTex) Or you missed a reference ? It all depends on the seriousness of this error. Why didn't you answer my question right below your question ? If you answer it, we might have a clearer picture of what happened. Please do not put another question in an answer box of the other question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I used latex.. I have checked and later l have corrected but date was expire..So they will not except it anymore.

Comment: Actually I a new here..So I did not know the rules..I have deleted that comment.